# How to know if a JR train has unreserved seats?

Tags: trains, japan

On Japan, most trains have at least one car for unreserved seats but not always. Is there a way to know if a train has such seats? Unless I missed it the JR machines to book tickets and check time schedules don't give you that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Japan Guide](https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2018.html) goes into which trains offer unreserved seating and which don't:

> Most shinkansen trains offer both non-reserved seats (自由席, jiyūseki) and reserved seats (指定席, shiteiseki) in separate cars. **Only the Hayabusa, Hayate and Komachi trains on the Tohoku Shinkansen and Hokkaido Shinkansen and the Kagayaki trains on the Hokuriku Shinkansen are fully reserved and do not carry non-reserved seating.**

If you're not sure, you can check the train you'll be taking ahead of time on [HyperDia](http://www.hyperdia.com/en/).

If there is an "unreserved seat" option under "seat fee", then that train has unreserved seating. Otherwise, it doesn't. Note that you still have to pay a "seat fee" even for unreserved seating. This is because the "fare" is actually the same as a regular train, and then the "seat fee" is a combination of the "limited express fee" and seat reservation fee.

Note that if you're on holiday in Japan and travelling with the JR Pass, you can request a free seat reservation by visiting the ticket desk at the station.

Comment: +1 for Hyperdia, a must-have for train travel in Japan and great if you have a JR rail pass